# Can't deploy Maven jar (MDB) on Jboss 6

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

I am using jboss6, message driven bean, hibernate and maven2 in my application when i try to compile my mdb using maven2 and  deploy on jboss6 i get the following error:

```
Failed to create Resource MessageBean.jar - cause: java.lang.Exception:Failed to start deployment [vfs:///opt/jboss6/server/default/deploy/MessageBean.jar] during deployment of 'MessageBean.jar' - cause: java.lang.RuntimeException:org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS): DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES: Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=MessageBean.jar,name=MessageBean,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies: Dependency "interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated") DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory" is in error due to the following reason(s): Instantiated -> org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException:Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS): DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES: Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=MessageBean.jar,name=MessageBean,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies: Dependency "interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated") DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory" is in error due to the following reason(s): Instantiated
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MessageBean</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MessageBean Java EE 6 EJB</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-timerservice-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <!--
             <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
             -->
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>

            <version>6.0</version>
            <!-- Added below -->
            <type>jar</type>
<!--                        modified by varsha -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <!-- end -->
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Java.Net Maven2 Repository, hosts the javaee-api dependency</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-snapshot</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>

<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>

                    <jbossHome>/opt/jboss6/server/default/deploy</jbossHome>

                    <jbossHome>/home/varsha/Downloads/jboss-6.0.0.Final/</jbossHome>
                    <serverName>default</serverName>
                    <fileName>target/MessageBean.jar</fileName>
                    <path>/UltimateSMS</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
        <finalName>MessageBean</finalName>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>endorsed</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>  
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I am not using ejb3 timer in my application as of now

What seems  to be the problem ? 
please help :(

Answer (score 2):

the dendency "jboss-ejb3-timerservice-spi" is most likely your problem.  not sure why you need to depend on that, but you certainly shouldn't be including it in your deployment.  if you *do* need it as a dependency for some reason, it should be marked as scope "provided".  all of those jboss dependencies and any other of those jars which are in the jboss lib directory should be marked as scope "provided".  generally, your app should not contain any jars which are part of the jboss server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at the time of your .jar deployment something has already instantiated the `TimerServiceFactory`.

Check your dependencies, I once had a similar problem where one of the jars I had as a maven dependency actually had a jboss.xml in its META-INF folder and was binding a bean I was using to a JNDI name I was already using.

Its a pain to search your dependencies, but this looks like its conflicting with something.

Its possible that one of your dependencies depends on an older version of `interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory` and it gets instantiated before yours.

Check your .m2 folder and see if you have 2 versions of jboss-ejb3-timerservice-spi downloaded.