# Can't deploy MDB connected to RA using JBOSS 6.4.2 GA

Tags: maven, jboss6.x, jboss-mdb, tibco-rv, resource-adapter

I have a problem deploying a MDB connected to a Tibco RV Resource Adapter, but while the RA is correctly deployed, the MDB is raising issues that I could not solve despite several attempts.

This is what I have tried to make my MDB deployed in connection to a Resource Adapter.

1. I have deployed my RA (tibco-adapter-ra2.rar): it is a RA integrated with TIBCO RV middleware. In attachment you can see the rar file of the tibco-adapter-ra2 maven project)
2. The RA has its logic in another maven project, which I have named tibco-adapter-jar (project attached as well)
3. There is a second maven jar project (tibco-adapter-msg-listener), containing just the MessageListener, and it is a dependency of tibco-adapter-jar project

So far, no problem. I can deploy the Tibco Adapter RA, without any further configuration into the standalone.xml file.

The problem (ERROR 1): I can't deploy the tibco-adapter-ear, made with tibco-adapter-ejb (it contains the MDB to connect to Tibco Adapter RA, both of them are attached as well) because of the following error:

The MDB uses Annotation to refer the Message Listener interface:

```
import com.ericsson.jee.sep.tibco.adapter.api.TibcoRvMessageListener; 
// from tibco-adapter-msg-listener JAR, so also tibco-adapter-ejb refers that library
     @MessageDriven(name="TibcoRvMDB",
      messageListenerInterface=TibcoRvMessageListener.class, 
              activationConfig={})
    @ResourceAdapter(value="tibco-adapter-ra2.rar")
    public class TibcoRvMessageBean implements TibcoRvMessageListener
    ...
```

> Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found (see Error1_Deployment_EAR_1.txt for the complete Stack Trace)

I have also edited the `standalone.xml` with the following configuration:

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.5">
              ...
            <mdb>               
              <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="tibco-adapter-ra2.rar"/>
              ...
          </mdb>
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
              <resource-adapter id="tibco-resource-adapter">
                  <archive>tibco-adapter-ra2.rar</archive>
              </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

The ERROR 2 after this configuration is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014521: No message listener of type com.ericsson.jee.sep.tibco.adapter.api.TibcoRvMessageListener found in resource adapter tibco-adapter-ra2 (see Error2_Deployment_EAR_2.txt for the complete Stack Trace).

The `TibcoRvMessageListener` is not the traditional JMS Message Listener, but a Tibco RV Message Listener.

I have seen similar issues raised in the past, but some of the suggestions have been already applied (see `standalone.xml` configuration), without resolving the issue.

I really need a support here, since I'm not able to find a way forward.

**Where I'm doing wrong?**

Kind Regards,
Pierluigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my issue was quite similar to this one:

[[Can't deploy Maven jar (MDB) on Jboss 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304880/cant-deploy-maven-jar-mdb-on-jboss-6][1])

But basically the problem was in a wrong maven structure. I have solved aligning my maven project structure to that one available on Github:

[https://github.com/timothysparg/JCA-Inflow-Wildfly][1]

In my original project I have tried to deploy RA and EAR separately, while the GitHub project has shown another approach: one single EAR containing RAR and EJB with the JAR (containing the business logic of RAR) included among dependencies with provided. That's made the trick for my project.

Comment: Yes, correct: in the end, the only way to make it working and succesfully deploy is to have in a single EAR both EJB (MDB, TibcoRvMessageListener) and RA (JAR, Tibco RA business logic). That made the trick for my above described issue. Thanks a lot, Pierluigi